# Android activate BroadcastReceiver only when phone is locked or app in background

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have a chat application and I want my GCM Broadcast to activate only when the phonescreen is locked or the app is not active (home button, not app killed!)

I tried the following:

```
boolean receiver_working = false;

public void enableBroadcastReceiver(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
    filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
    filter.addCategory("com.flipflopdev.epvp_aj1987_chat");
    registerReceiver(new GcmBroadcastReceiver(), filter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    receiver_working = true;
   }

public void disableBroadcastReceiver(){
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), GcmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disabled broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    receiver_working = false;
   }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(receiver_working) {
        disableBroadcastReceiver();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(!receiver_working) {
        enableBroadcastReceiver();
    }
}
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
    if(receiver_working) {
        disableBroadcastReceiver();
    }
}
```

The problem is that onResume() is firing even the activity just starts, thats why I have the boolean variable. When I leave the app now through home button, the GCM Notifications fire up like they should (because BR is activated), when I come back into the app it says BR deactivated but notifications still fire up if send.

Where is my mistake?